# How do you put a User Name/Password in JSON format?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Can you please tell me how to put a username/password into JSON format so it can be used in an AJAX query I'm trying to write?

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what's being asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/some_server_side_script',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        username: $('#username').val(),
        password: $('#password').val(),
    }),
    success: function(result) {
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

In this example I have explicitly specified the `Content-Type` HTTP request header to `application/json` so that the server knows the exact content type being sent. I have also used the native [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) javascript function to convert the javascript object to a JSON string that will be sent to the server.

So assuming that you had `#username` and `#password` input fields in your DOM the following request payload will be sent to the server:

```
POST /some_server_side_script HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 39
Connection: close

{"username":"john","password":"secret"}
```